# Display json format data in smarty chartjs

Tags: javascript, php, json, smarty

```
<script>
{literal}
var ctx = document.getElementById('myGlaciermassChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels: [{/literal}

            {foreach from=$glaciermass item=year name=glaciermassloop}
                {if $smarty.foreach.glaciermassloop.last}
                    "{$year.Year}"
                {else}
                    "{$year.Year}",
                {/if}

            {/foreach}

            {literal}],

            datasets: [{
                   label: 'Mean Glacier mass Level',
                   data: [{/literal}

                       {foreach from=$glaciermass item=year name=glaciermassloop}
                           {if $smarty.foreach.glaciermassloop.last}
                               "{$year.Mean-cumulative-mass-balance}"
                           {else}
                               "{$year.Mean-cumulative-mass-balance}",
                           {/if}
                       {/foreach}

                       {literal}],
                   backgroundColor: [
                       'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                       'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                       'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                       'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                       'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                       'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                   ],
                   borderColor: [
                       'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                       'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                       'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                       'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                       'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                       'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                   ],
                   borderWidth: 1
               }]
           },
           options: {
               scales: {
                   yAxes: [{
                       ticks: {
                           suggestedMax: 0,
                           suggestedMin:-30,
                           beginAtZero: true
                       }
                   }]
               }
           }
       });

{/literal}
</script>
```

I am using Chart.js and the data from an API endpoint is not displaying the right Mean values on the screen. I have tried many different ways and I have even tried selecting an index, but it doesn't work.Currently the Mean values are showing only 0s on the chart for all the years instead of the actual values from the json - Here is the json itself. https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/glacier-mass-balance/glaciers_json/data/6270342ca6134dadf8f94221be683bc6/glaciers_json.json.

```
<?php

$url ='https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/glacier-mass-balance/glaciers_json/data/6270342ca6134dadf8f94221be683bc6/glaciers_json.json';

$response = file_get_contents($url);
$GlaciermassData= json_decode($response, true);

$smarty->assign('glaciermass', $GlaciermassData);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing each index by number?